# Find all video files in downloads folder and move to new folder

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to find all the downloaded mp4 and mkv files in my downloads folder. The specific files i'm looking for are all in different places in downloads some in subdirectories in the downloads' folder some just files in the downloads' folder.

this is what i have so far

```
import os
import shutil
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\carte\Downloads')
path = os.path.abspath(r'.\Movie_files')
for p, d, f in os.walk(r'C:\Users\carte\Downloads'):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith('.mp4') or file.endswith('.mkv'):
            print('-------------------------------------------------------')
            print('File Path:' + os.path.abspath(file))
            print(f"Movie File:{file}")
            print('-------------------------------------------------------')
            movie_file_path =os.path.abspath(file)
            shutil.move(movie_file_path, path)
```

but i continue to get this error when runnning

```
-------------------------------------------------------
File Path:C:\Users\carte\Downloads\1917.mp4
Movie File:1917.mp4
-------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\carte\\Downloads\\1917.mp4' -> 'C:\\Users\\carte\\Downloads\\Movie_files\\1917.mp4'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/carte/OneDrive/Documents/Code/Practice/practice_os.py", line 13, in <module>
    shutil.move(movie_file_path, path)
  File "C:\Users\carte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 802, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\carte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\carte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\carte\\Downloads\\1917.mp4'
PS C:\Users\carte\OneDrive\Documents\Code>
```

Why is the shutil.move looking for the file im trying to move in the destination?

Comment: Print out `p`, `d` and `f`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem when organizing my code it was something to do with the `\`in my strings I needed to use `\\` instead.

I'll paste my code below for what I coded.
It works so you can try to update it for your needs.

```
from shutil import move as mve
from time import sleep as slp
import os

os.chdir('c:\\Users\\Charlie\\Downloads')

source_path = "c:\\Users\\Charlie\\Downloads"
dest_path = "c:\\users\\Charlie\\Downloads\\FORGOT TO USE A PATH"

def move_file():
     # get the current date
            src_path = os.path.join(source_path, f)
            # create the folders if they arent already exists
            if not os.path.exists(dest_path):
                os.makedirs(dest_path)
            if not os.path.exists(f"{dest_path}\\{f}"):
                mve(src_path, dest_path)
            else:
                print("File already exists")

while True:
    files = os.listdir("c:\\Users\\Charlie\\Downloads")
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.zip'):
            dest_path = "c:\\users\\Charlie\\Downloads\\Zip"
            move_file()
        elif f.endswith('.pdf') or f.endswith('.docx') or f.endswith('.doc') or f.endswith('.ppt') or f.endswith('.pptx'):
            dest_path = "c:\\users\\Charlie\\Downloads\\Documents"
            move_file()
        elif f.endswith('.jpg') or f.endswith('.png'):
            dest_path = "c:\\users\\Charlie\\Downloads\\Pictures"
            move_file()
        elif f.endswith('.tmp'):
            break
        elif not os.path.isdir(f):
            dest_path = "c:\\users\\Charlie\\Downloads\\Unsorted"
            move_file()
    slp(10)
```

Comment: So using (r’path\path\path’) for a raw string didn’t work for you ?

Comment: And listdir wouldn’t work because I need to go into sub directory’s and look for video files also. not just the files in the download folder but files within the folders in the downloads

Comment: So r'/path/path' wouldn't work in the end I used "C:\\Users\\..." With the subdirectories, the best way to do it would probably be some form of recursion with some form of algorithmic search

Answer (score -1):

Check if the destination directory exists.

Also, it may be a problem that your destination is actually part of your source tree, so you may want to put the files elsewhere.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27488013)

Comment: Thanks - I was just trying to be helpful.  I'll hold off until I get a better reputation.  LOL I just lost 2 points here.

Comment: Thanks for taking it sportily. The intention is never to discourage a poster rather to segregate actual answers and suggestions. I didn't swallowed up your 2 cents by the way :)